# I tried ro setSize() to a JButton and this happened

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Was trying to do an `ActionListener` `JButton`, but the size of the button does not change to what I want to, it follows the size of the frame. I am very new and read many tutorials on that, seems right, but it doesn't work.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class TimeTester extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private int x = 10;
    private static TimeTester test = new TimeTester();
    private static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private static JButton button = new JButton("Next Frame");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        button.setLocation(100, 100);
        button.setVisible(true);
        button.addActionListener(test);
        button.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(50, 60));
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(test);
        System.out.println(test.calcTime());
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }

    private synchronized long calcTime(){
        double a;
        long start = System.nanoTime();

        long end = System.nanoTime();
        return (end - start);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawLine(x, x, 100 + x, 100 + x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I don't find `I tried [to setSize()] a JButton`. (`button.setMaximumSize()`?)  Please be extra careful with a question's title: double-check it right before posting. Correct the error in this one.

Comment: **Change the size of a button by making the text longer, the font larger, use a bigger icon or, most commonly, *call [`AbstractButton.setMargin(Insets)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMargin(java.awt.Insets)).*** **General Tips:** 1) `private static TimeTester test = new TimeTester();` get rid of that. The `TimeTester` class **is a** `TimeTester`. 2) Don't use `static` for GUI components, it creates more problems than it solves. 3) `frame.setLayout(null);` Java GUIs have to work ..

Comment: .. on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 4) `frame.setVisible(true);` Call that last, immediately after `pack()` to get the right size. .. I'll stop there, because there's more wrong with that code than right. Toss it out and do the tutorial.